# Is exists any nuget package for oauth 1.0 that compatible with asp.net core?

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I tried very hard to find and could not.

I need OAuth 1.0 since I need to use intuit QB which not support oauth 2.0 yet.
thanks!

Comment: for now - the best I found is https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter - not generic, but implementation for twitter

Answer (score 2):

I had the same struggle the past few days in finding an implementation for .NET Core that supports OAuth 1.0. The library from Chilkat may be the only one out there. Not sure if the OAuth API inside the library requires the commercial license or not.

- https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csOAuth1Ref.html
- https://www.chilkatsoft.com/dotnet-core.asp

Another solid option is to use the portable version RestSharp which has a built-in OAuth1Authenticator: https://www.myget.org/feed/restsharp-portable/package/nuget/FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable.OAuth1

Comment: Could you add example code to use this (if u already implemented it...) thanks

Comment: I haven't implemented it, but there is example code here:
https://www.example-code.com/csharp/oauth1_signature.asp 
And from the example it's clear that a commercial license is required.

Answer (score 1):

I used OAuth.DotNetCore for OAuth 1.0 with .Net Core 2.1, it worked fine.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/OAuth.DotNetCore/